# find the increasing percentage of values

Tags: sql-server

I need to find the increasing percentage of value. I have a columns like this

[image]

I have to group by name values and consider every 5 values for calculating the Increasing percentage .
For example I will consider first 5 values and increasing avg will be calculated for 5th value then for 6th and so on. below is the example for the same.
[image]

I could achieve in EXCEL with formal = `=((((I5+I6+I7+I8+I9)/5)-I9)/I9)*100)`, however in SQL i tried creating an cursor but couldnt achieve for increasing value.

Hence any help is appreciated.

Comment: post sample data as formatted text , not images

Comment: And explain what you *actually* want, not how you think it will be implemented. Do you want a running total? Running percentile? Excel already has such functions by the way. Summing them one by one is wasteful and doesn't help to understand what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try something like this (but pls next time post in correct way your sample data and desired output.  See the tour StackOverflow):

```
SELECT ID, NAME, VALUE
,(AVG(0.0+VALUE) OVER (  ORDER BY ID ROWS 4 PRECEDING) - VALUE) / VALUE *100 AS INCR_AVG
FROM TAB1
```

Output:

```
ID          NAME       VALUE       INCR_AVG
----------- ---------- ----------- ---------------------------------------
1           ABC        486         0.000000
2           ABC        360         17.500000
3           ABC        174         95.402200
4           ABC        283         15.106000
5           ABC        386         -12.487000
6           ABC        154         76.233700
7           ABC        589         -46.146000
8           ABC        458         -18.340600
9           ABC        658         -31.762900
10          ABC        456         1.535000
```

Comment: @esta Thanks .. This helped me alot and i will keep in mind to share the details in text form instead of image.